# is there a way to code the C# operator ^= in php

Tags: c#, php

I am converting a C# routine to php

do not understand how to do this C#

```
bool ret = false;

ret ^= (y * multiple[i] + constant[i] < x);
```

its the operator  `^=`   ??

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-assignment-operator

Comment: Also, PHP has the `^=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: in PHP you can use the same `^=` operator.

The `x ^= y` is equivalent to `x = x ^ y` with `^` the bitwise xor operator.

In PHP `^` is also the bitwise xor operator. So it is the same in PHP, you can use:

```
$ret ^= ($y * $multiple[$i] + $constant[$i] < $x);
```

given of course that `$y`, `$multiple`, `$i$`, etc. all have an equivalent meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is a feature of assigning and using an operator at the same time. Usually denoted by ending with `=`. For example:

```
int b = 5;
Console.WriteLine(b += 2); //Add 2 to b and print it
b *= 2; //Equivalent of b = b * 2;
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The above code prints:

`7
14`

Hope this helps you better understand how assignment and arithmetic operators work. Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator) to some reference on the particular operator in your question.